# SSRS 2008R2, Error "Must declare variable @PREndDate"

Tags: variables, reporting-services, parameters, declare

The following query works great in SQL, but when I use it in SSRS, I get an error of "Must declare variable @PREndDate".  If I use actual date, then it is fine, but it does not like the use of the parameter for some reason; I have the parameter set as Date/Time.  I had another friend try it, and they were able to run it with no issues, so it makes me wonder if there is a default setting somewhere causing this issue.

```
   select PRCo, PRGroup, PREndDate, EarnCode
     from PRTH

    where EarnCode IN ('13', '14') 
    and PREndDate = @PREndDate
```

Comment: Where's the declaration of  `@PREndDate`?

Comment: I declared the parameter in SQL, but I should not have to declare it in my Query for SSRS.

Comment: I have it setup as a Parameter with Date/Time format.  In the past this has always been fine.  It would give you the calendar option to select a date when you view the report.

Comment: I thought I would try uploading the report to the web, and the SSRS report works in the web, it just will not view in Microsoft Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using this as your dataset in SSRS, you need to map the parameter to your report parameter in the **Dataset** properties.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have my parameter setup in the Dataset Properties

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna assume that what you're missing is the declaration of your `@PREndDate` just write this:

```
Declare @PREndDate as datetime set @PREndDate= '2015-09-15'
```

Or any date you want to set as your `@PREndDate`

Comment: I declared the parameter in SQL, but I should not have to declare it in my Query for SSRS.